# Removing index.php from codeigniter 2.1.3

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Before I open this post, I did spent three days try to figure out this, but no luck at all, so please help me out. Thanks~~~~

Ok, this is what I’ve done so far:

1. Install a fresh copy of CI 2.1.3, no any name change on any folders
2. Create a new .htaccess file to CI ROOT directory with all structures that I found on the Google
3. Change config[‘index_page’] to an empty, eg. config[‘index_page’] =’‘;
4. Set config[‘uri_protocol’] = ‘REQUEST_URI’ or ‘QUERY_STRING’
5. Even restart the MAMP ( PHP 5.4) every time I made the change above
6. Enabled:  LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so in httpd.conf
7. Add ‘Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews’ in https.conf ( the only thing I am not sure )
8. ( I have no idea what should I try now V_V )

Then, I got this:

yes working:  http://ci.dev/index.php/welcome/index

not working:  http://ci.dev/welcome/index

Here are some details of what I have now:

**.htaccess file:**

```
# I got 500 error if I uncommend this line: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#http://ci.dev/index.php/welcome/index  this is works fine only if the above line commend out
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/?$1 [L]
# I got 500 error if I uncommend this line: </IfModule>
```

**config.php**

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';
//$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

**host file**

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 test.dev
127.0.0.1 ci.dev
```

**httpd.conf file**

```
#the following line also enabled
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so  in httpd.conf

...

# The following code I placed at the bottom of https.conf file

NameVirtualHost *

<VirtualHost *>
 ServerName localhost
 DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *> 
 ServerName ci.dev
 DocumentRoot /Users/coda/Sites/ci
 <Directory /Users/coda/Sites/ci>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *> 
 ServerName test.dev
 DocumentRoot /Users/coda/Sites/test
</VirtualHost>
```

Please HELP ME OUT ~~~~

Thanks

=================================================================

Thanks everyone who try to help me out here. I finally got it works, I think somehow I overcomplicated things after overlooking something simple.

I just install another copy of CI2 and only change the .htaccess file with:

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Then, it all works~!!!! –

Answer (score 3):

Try this .htaccess (put this into root of the project directory i.e. /chat here):

```
# To remove index.php from URL

RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase /chat
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Put `RewriteBase` if you have project in a sub directory otherwise remove it

Answer (score 1):

Have the.htaccess file in the application root directory, along with the index.php file. (Check if the htaccess extension is correct , Bz htaccess.txt did not work for me.)

And Add the following rules to .htaccess file,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Then find the following line in your application/config/config.php file

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Set the variable empty as below.

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

That's it, it worked for me.

If it doesn't work further try to replace following variable with these parameters  ('AUTO', 'PATH_INFO', 'QUERY_STRING', 'REQUEST_URI', and 'ORIG_PATH_INFO') one by one

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

Comment: place .htaccess in application folder not in the root

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Note:

**htdocs** is the root folder

**ci_intro** is the code igniter's folder

if we have the same case, then your .htaccess should be like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /ci_intro/

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Notice the **RewriteBase /ci_intro/** change the ci_info to your codeigniter's folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

`RewriteEngine on`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

`RewriteRule .* /codeigniterNameFolder/index.php/$0 [PT,L]`

change codeigniterNameFolder :)